# Backbone Collections - not able to set a 'rank' using set method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

In my backbone.marionette app, I am trying to set a model attribute 'rank' as it's loop index. here is the code of my collection:

```
 AngryCats = Backbone.Collection.extend({
          model:AngryCat,
          initialize: function(cats){
              var rank = 1;
              _.each(cats, function(cat){
                    cat.set('rank', rank);
                  rank++;
              })
          }
      });
```

But I am getting error as :

```
TypeError: cat.set is not a function
cat.set('rank', rank);
```

any one tell me what is wrong here? ( please check the fiddle link for complete coding )

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y6nH5/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing array of javascript objects. But the `set` is only available in `Backbone.Model` instance. Only after initialisation, every single object converted into `Backbone.Model` Object.

You have to do like

```
 var rank = 1;
 _.each(cats, function(cat){
     cat.rank = rank;
     rank++;
  })
```